# How to type into webpage form using Excel VBA if the page source does not contain "id" attribute

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to use Excel VBA to open an URL and login to the webpage.

I am not able to type in the user name and password fields.

I tried using getelementsbytagname. I am not sure about the right syntax.

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

Sub MyGmail()
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://xxxxxxxxxxx"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document`enter code here`
Debug.Print HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("hwiDialogTable").getElementsByTagName("form").Item(0) ' trying to see if am bale to access elements
HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "abcd" 'Enter your email id here
HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "xxxxx" 'Enter your password here
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End If
End Sub
```

This is the source code for the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Login to TWS/WebAdmin</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">if (window.top != window.self) { window.top.location.href = window.self.location.href; } </script>
   <style type="text/css">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100% }
      * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt }
      h1 { font-size: 14pt }
      table.hwiDialogTable { position: absolute; width: 100%; height:100%; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0 }
      td.hwiDialogTd { text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; background: #dddddd }
      div.hwiDialogDiv { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 500px; background: white; text-align: left; padding: 20px }
      div.hwiDialogDivCorner { height: 2px; width: 2px; border: 1px solid #E0E0E0; position: absolute }
      a.menuitem { text-decoration:none }
      a:hover { background-color:blue; color:white; }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="hwiDialogTable">
<tr><td class="hwiDialogTd">
<div class="hwiDialogDiv">
<div class="hwiDialogDivCorner" style="top: 0; left: 0; border-right-color: white; border-bottom-color: white"></div>
<div class="hwiDialogDivCorner" style="top: 0; right: 0; border-left-color: white; border-bottom-color: white"></div>
<div class="hwiDialogDivCorner" style="bottom: 0; right: 0; border-left-color: white; border-top-color: white"></div>
<div class="hwiDialogDivCorner" style="bottom: 0; left: 0; border-right-color: white; border-top-color: white"></div>
<h1>Login to TWS/WebAdmin</h1>
<br/><br/>
<form action="/" method="post">
   <table>
      <tr><td>User&nbsp;name:</td><td><input type="text" name="PHP_AUTH_USER" value="" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="PHP_AUTH_PW" value="" autocomplete="off"/></td></tr>
   </table>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var hwiNameInput = window.document.getElementsByName('PHP_AUTH_USER');
      if (hwiNameInput.length > 0) {
         hwiNameInput[0].focus();
      }
   </script>
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Login" />
   <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
</form>
</div></td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

The web page opens but nothing happens after that.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's POST data you need to pass the variables along with the page request.
This is one method.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "URL TO WEBPAGE" ' change this
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD" ' Change Username and password
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ("")
html = objHTTP.responseText

Debug.Print html
```

If that don't work you may need to use the send parameters.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
URL = "URL TO WEBPAGE" ' change this
objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False ' notice no username and password
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send("PHP_AUTH_USER=username,PHP_AUTH_PW=password") ' we put it here instead. 
' But I have never done username and password this way, it could be that you should use 
' objHTTP.send("PHP_AUTH_USER=username&PHP_AUTH_PW=password")
html = objHTTP.responseText

Debug.Print html
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your quick reply, i tried your code and for the first time i was getting something displayed in immediate window! -- but only the source code was returned in immediate window, could you please suggest what mistake would i be doing?

Comment: @Banwari That is what the code does. What are you expecting?

Comment: Hi Andreas, Am expecting the code to navigate to the url and type in username and password into the webpage and login automatically. Please advise!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `name` attributes

```
MyBrowser.document.querySelector("[name='PHP_AUTH_USER']").value = "username"

MyBrowser.document.querySelector("[name='PHP_AUTH_PW']").value = "password"
```

I tested with your html in an html file on disk

```
Public Sub test()
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "url"  'or file to test html file containing html sample
        While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document.querySelector("[name='PHP_AUTH_USER']")
            .Focus
            .Value = "username"
        End With
        With .document.querySelector("[name='PHP_AUTH_PW']")
            .Focus
            .Value = "password"
        End With
        Stop '<== delete me later
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Reading:**

1. Css [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
2. [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Comment: Hi Thanks much for your quick reply i tried the above but still did not get the values typed automatically in the fields. should i make any other changes?

Comment: try to .focus on the fields first. Otherwise try .document.parentWindow.execScript "document.querySelector('[name=PHP_AUTH_USER]').setAttribute('value','username');"       also try with 'value' replaced with 'textContent'

Comment: Hi Qharr, FYI only -once the url loads the username input field will be highlighted automatically we dont have to click on it to highlight. i tried you above method and got the error -- "Run-time error '-21477023179(800706b5)':
Automation error
The interface is unknown" on line While .busy Or .readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Wend. i feel we are not able to access the type in fields yet. please advise!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the getElementsByName method to get the elements, code as below:

```
Sub login()

    Const Url$ = "<login page url>"

    Dim UserName As String, Password As String

    UserName = "Dillion"
    Password = "password"

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie

        .navigate Url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = True

        Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
        Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("PHP_AUTH_USER")(0)
        Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("PHP_AUTH_PW")(0)

        oLogin.Value = UserName
        oPassword.Value = Password

        Dim submitbtn As Object
        Set submitbtn = .document.getElementsByName("action")(0)
        submitbtn.Click

        'You could also use the following code to submite the form.
        '.document.forms(0).submit

    End With

End Sub

Sub ieBusy(ie As Object)
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for sharing your answer. however am still unable to login into the page, above code navigates to the url but does not type in username and password to login. i got the error message " Run-time error '-2147467259(80004005)':
Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"  Are we just assigning the values and not typing in them into the fields, please advise!